# Sharing from Android to Facebook: Make post appear on user wall and page wall simultaneously

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent

I am creating an Android app that will include the ability to share. Besides the normal SEND intent that lets users pick provider I have Facebook-specific sharing.

Whenever a user completes a challenge, the results should automatically be posted to the user's wall. In addition, I have a Facebook page for my app and I wan't the user's wall post to appear on my Facebook page as well.

How can this be done? My first thought was to "tag" my page with the @symbol, but as far as I know that is only possible if the user has already liked my page?

The outcome I am looking for is for the shared post to appear both on the user's wall and on my Facebook page simultaneously.

> For example: James just completed the Gold Rush Challenge and is
>   ranked #52!

Comment: You really should not do this unless the user is explicitly aware that they're posting to your page (in which case you should use the Feed Dialog - WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder). The reason is because posts on your page are essentially public, and you should not be exposing a user's information unless they explicitly agree to it.

Comment: That is a fair point. Is it possible to add an extra permission the user can accept or deny during the authentication process that asks if the user accepts to post to the page as well? Sorry if this is slightly off topic, I'm just trying to solve the problem.

Comment: It is not possible. If you want to share to anywhere that's not the user's timeline, you need to use the share dialog.